# C++ - odeint solution to system varies significantly

Tags: c++, matlab, ode, odeint

I am using odeint to solve for a system of 4 coupled equations, which simulate the vibration of a vehicle while it is driving. I was hoping my results would be similar to what I get in MATLAB, but that is unfortunately not happening. I have checked my equations multiple times and there is no error there, so the issue has to be happening during the integration.

I have coded out the solution in MATLAB to verify what I am getting from the C++ script. Using the same conditions, this is the solution I get from odeint:
[image]

And this is the same solution in MATLAB:
[image]

I did not expect the micro-oscillations seen in MATLAB to show up in the odeint results, but most of the values are not even close to correct. Am I using the wrong inegrator, or will odeint just not work for this application?

The c++ file can be found on Github, [here.](https://github.com/armstrongc93/2dof_vibration) The class named "coupledODE" is the system of equations pertaining to my system, and odeint is impemented in the main function.

Comment: The github link is not working. And can you plot the Matlab solution with a higher resolution? Maybe even plot both graphs in one diagram?

Comment: @headmyshoulder it has been corrected, I apologize.

Comment: Could you also try to integrate the solution with integrate_const(make_dense_output(1E-6, 1E-10, rk5()), ...); Just to make sure that it does not depend on the precision.

Comment: Ahh, there is a factor of 10 missing

Comment: That solution is even further off from the desired output; does this mean it is due to the precision?

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: Are you sure, you have the same initial conditions and constants?

Comment: In regards to the factor of 10 missing, in this case, yes it is more or less off by a factor of 10. When I extend the solution to 0-10s, the solution fails to reach stability. IT oscillates more wildly than it should, or it behaves similar to resonance, which is not correct.

Comment: I can check the constants one more time, but the initial conditions are just zero, and that shows up in the system output from the cpp file

Comment: Short of the math though, there is no obvious reason why the code is not working as intended?

Comment: No, it should work. At least I would be very surprised if this ODE behaves different in Matlab.

Comment: Ok, well that's at least a bit reassuring. Perhaps the order operations are being carried out in the equations is not correct. I will fully comb through that (and the original derivation) and see if I can catch anything.

Comment: Make sure to select the class 4 model and set the time step somewhat smaller so that you reach the sampling frequency for the fast oscillations, `dt=0.01` or `dt=0.005` should do. With the "Class 4" data from the C++ code and the remaining constants (compare the dampening parameters) from the matlab file I can reproduce the second, matlab graph in python, both with `lsoda-scipy.integrate.odeint` and my own adaptive RK4 variant -- only there does not happen any step size variation, it is `dt=0.0033` without change for a relative error of `1e-5`.

Comment: It's odd, when I reduce the time step the system solution is entirely incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C++ code you never execute the `calcRadialFreq()` procedure and thus have `radFreq=0` unchanged from its initialization, supplying a constant drift term but not the small oscillations.

Incorporating this line of computation in the `getRoadValues()` procedure above it will make the result visually identical to the Matlab graph.

Provided one honors the forcing frequency of 20Hz with a sampling rate of the output larger than 40Hz. A time step of `dt=0.01` for 100Hz will do nicely.

---

I'd also propose to compute the ODE function in small, easily to read bits. This should help with comparing different versions and catch errors. It could for instance take the form

```
void operator()(state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, double t)
{
    double wave_f = car.stiffness_f*road.A*sin((road.radFreq)*t);
    double wave_r = car.stiffness_r*road.A*sin((road.radFreq)*t-(2*pi*(car.frontLength+car.rearLength))/road.L);

    double term1f = car.stiffness_f*x[0] + car.damping_f*x[1];
    double term1r = car.stiffness_r*x[0] + car.damping_r*x[1];
    double term2f = car.stiffness_f*x[2] + car.damping_f*x[3];
    double term2r = car.stiffness_r*x[2] + car.damping_r*x[3];
    double term3f = -term1f + term2f*car.frontLength + wave_f;
    double term3r = -term1r - term2r*car.rearLength  + wave_r;

    dxdt[0] = x[1];
    dxdt[1] = (1 / car.mass)*( term3f                  + term3r                 );
    dxdt[2] = x[3];
    dxdt[3] = (1/car.inertia)*(-term3f*car.frontLength + term3r*car.rearLength  );
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much! I really appreciate it. It definitely helps to have other eyes look over it.